# When i am printing an array in Swift its type(<__NSArrayM 0x60800024a1a0>) is also coming with it. Why?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, swift3, ios10

```
{let doctorId: NSNumber = (self.selectedDoctor["id"] as? NSNumber)!
        let referredTo:Dictionary = ["id":doctorId]
        var postParams = [String : Any]()
        postParams["referredTo"] = referredTo as AnyObject?


        if self.mCase != nil{

            if let patient:Patient = self.mCase.patient {
            postParams["patient"] = ["id":patient.id!]
            }

            if let mCaseId:NSNumber = self.mCase.id{
                postParams["medicalCase"] = ["id":mCaseId]
            }

            postParams["completeCase"]  = self.completeCase as AnyObject?
            postParams["includeAttachments"] = self.includeAttachment as AnyObject?

          let visitDict = NSMutableDictionary ()

            //let array = NSMutableArray()

            for dict in self.visitIds   {


               let indx : Int!  = (dict["visitID"] as? Int)!

                visitDict["visit"] =  ["id":indx!]
                self.visitArray.add(visitDict)
            }
           if self.completeCase {
                for visit in self.mCase.visits{
                var id = (visit as AnyObject).id!
                    visitDict["visit"] = ["id": id!]
                    self.visitArray.add(visitDict)
                }
            }


            postParams["referredVisits"]  = self.visitArray
        print(postParams["referredVisits"])
        }

        else{

         let patient:Dictionary  =   ["id":self.patientId]
            postParams["patient"] = patient as AnyObject?

        }

        marseResponse = MARSRequest.SendRequest("POST", postParams: postParams as [String : AnyObject]?,getParams: nil, service:.postpatientrererral)
```

}
This is how i am setting the parameters

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ACnsa.png) Xcode is showing `<__NSArrayM >` while printing the array and please guide me for how to remove this. Please refer the below image. It was working fine in `swift 2` but when I updated my code to `swift 3` this issue appears. This is happening when I am sending the parameters in `POST` Method. And May be because of this I am not able to parse the data.

[Data Parsing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BVN2L.png) this is how i am parsing the data

Comment: Are you just sending raw internal debug representation of array in POST request body?

Comment: while i am sending an empty array even then it is coming

Comment: why don't you try converting data in proper transmit format like JSON? Why're you using **internal representation** for this?

Comment: can you suggest me how to do this. I am new in the IOS. Any help would be great for me.may  be i am doing it in proper transit format. I am not sure

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about converting your data to JSON?

For example, using standard class [`JSONSerialization`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/jsonserialization):

```
let array = [
    [
        "visit": [
            "id": 2625
        ]
    ]
]
let data = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: array, options: [])
let string = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)
```

And then send `string` value?

Comment: i have added a image in the question about parsing the data. can you look at it and suugest me

Comment: Not able to implement this. Can you please look at the data parsing image?? in the code the issue is coming in post[referredVisits]